# Getting Checkbox Value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. This app has a basic form. The model for my form looks like the following:

```
public partial class User
{
    public bool Addon { get; set; }
}
```

In my form, I have the following HTML.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addon, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addon)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Addon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I currently don't have any code for the *Addon* in the controller.

I want to check if Checkbox was checked inside a different HTML to show hidden links that would only be available if the checkbox was checked.

How would I able to check it if the if statement was in a different HTML page? Because the checkbox would be checked at the moment at User Creation. Then once logging in, the index page would depend if the checkbox it checked or not.

An example would be

```
if (Addon == True)
{
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><a onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", 
        "Users") + "'");" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add User &raquo; 
         </a></p>
     </div>
}
```

Any ideas on how I could go about this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you already tried with jquery or javascript?

Comment: And where is your hidden links?

Comment: Selim, I have added an example. Hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: Yes it helped, I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60985313/5519709), please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `id` of checkbox and use Javascript to control if it's check like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addon, new { id ="chkAddon" })
```

Then use `is(":checked")` in Javascript would be like:

```
if ($('#chkAddon').is(":checked"))
{
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><a onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", 
        "Users") + "'");" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add User &raquo; 
         </a></p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I able to check it if the if statement was in a different HTML page? Because the checkbox would be checked at the moment at User Creation. Then once logging in, the index page would depend if the checkbox it checked or not.

Comment: So how do you get this `Addon` from another page? Do you have still same model on that page?

Comment: Yes it's the same model.

Comment: So can't you just use `@if(Model.Addon){
 <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><a onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", 
        "Users") + "'");" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add User &raquo; 
         </a></p>
    </div>
 }` ?

Comment: No it returns  `an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'User.Addon' `

Comment: What is your model `model.Addon` or  `User.Addon`? Just use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addon, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addon,"", new { @class = "check-btn" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Addon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a id="link" href="#"  style="display:none;">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".check-btn").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#link").css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                $("#link").css("display", "none");
            }
        });


</script>
```

you want to safety, need you use jquery ajax.